# github pages website changing based on Windows theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I am using GitHub pages with Jekyll, and the Ockham theme to display my website(https://wadingthrusecurity.com/).

Everything looks fine on my computer when I serve it as well as the live website. I've noticed that the theme colors change if the Windows theme isn't in Dark mode.

Is there a setting to turn this off?

Dark mode
[image: darkmode]

Light mode
[image: Light mode]

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide you config file?

Comment: The theme respects `prefers-color-scheme`, and you'd have to override that in stylesheets.